# SAP ODATA URI Query

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I wanted to pass multiple parameter as INPUT for ExpandedentitySet. Could anyone help on URI alone ? Tried many combinations but couldn't able to decode.

OData V2

Attempt 1:

```
/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCAR_GDP_MSG_SRV/GDP_MSG_HDRSET?$expand=GDP_MSG_NAV&$filter=Date eq 
    datetime'2019-03-01T00:00:00',Store eq '0010'
```

Attempt 2 - This URI sends only STORE as input and DATE has been discarded:

```
/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZCAR_GDP_MSG_SRV/GDP_MSG_HDRSET?$expand=GDP_MSG_NAV&$filter=Date eq 
    datetime'2019-03-01T00:00:00'$filter=Store eq '0010'
```

Comment: The OData V2 documentation answers already your question: https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#FilterSystemQueryOption → See the `and`, `or`, and `not` samples in the "Logical Operators" section of the 1st table there.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the filter as one expression for e.g.

```
?$filter=Date eq datetime'2019-03-01T00:00:00' and Store eq '0010'
```

you also can combine with the keyword `or` instead of `and` but this depenends on your usecase